# How do I get man2html pages to show in the browser?

Tags: 14.10, apache2.4

I am following the advice in [What is the best way to learn how to use Ubuntu with terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151488/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-how-to-use-ubuntu-with-terminal) Specifically at how to view the man pages in a web browser.

I followed the advice in [How do I make man pages open in a web browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339255/how-do-i-make-man-pages-open-in-a-web-browser/339268#339268) and used

`man -H[browser] <command>` (e.g. `man -Hfirefox man`)

(after installing groff) but it doesn't hyperlink to related commands.

The original article mentions the commands have hyperlinks to other commands using man2page. I `apt-get install man2html` and then navigate to the page mentioned at `http://localhost/cgi-bin/man/man2html` When I navigate to the page, I get

*The requested URL /cgi-bin/man/man2html was not found on this server.*

I restarted the Apache2 server that is installed with Ubuntu (and it works with the default page at `http://localhost/`).

I am using man2html man-1.6g, Apache 2.4.10, and Ubuntu 14.10

**How do I get man2html pages to show in the browser?**

#### Update

I found an answer on the Ubuntu forums and posted it below with a link to the forum post. It works for me and I hope it is useful to others.

Comment: @AibaraIduas I have to wait 48 hours before I can accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Ah, forgot about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this answer on the forums:

`sudo a2enmod cgid`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Because man2html is a CGI script, Apache2 needs the module `mod_cgid` enabled to serve the contents of the page. It was [split into two binaries](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/man2html/1.6g-2): one the html converter and the other the CGI interface.

Source:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2199030